# function for language C which has same as sparse in Matlab

Tags: c

I want to assemble a lot of small local matrices into one global sparse matrix. And also after assembly process I need another functions for deleting some specific row and column at the global sparse matrix.

So the best option is "sparse" in Matlab. However, I want use this kind of function in Language C. Is there any function or library for using this kind of function in language C?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you done a google search? “C library for sparse matrices” provides quite a few hits.